# AWS RDS upgrade of Postgres Database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, logical-replication, read-replication, postgres-11

As you may already know, Postgres will stop supporting v11 and we are using a version of it. The upgrade in the AWS end is quite straight forward but there is a few points that I don't understand.

-We are using logical replication from Application database into this Postgres v11 database, will this upgrade break it? In documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html), if I understand correctly it should not break it. Since our database is subscriber, it does not have a replication slot.

-What will happen to endpoint? I don't fully understand that if host information is going to change or not.

-And latest point, we have also a read replica for this database, will this upgrade affect that one? From the documentation that I share, I kinda get mixed signals.